# Adding image to h:commandbutton where type="reset"

Tags: jsf

I am trying add image to h:commandbutton where type="reset" button is not resetting values of the form.. If I remove the image tag the reset button works fine.. I also tried with h:graphic image but image and reset button both will appear in UI.Please help me to come out..

```
       <h:commandButton id="clearConfirmVal" type="reset"  value="/images/Reset.png" title="#{str['button.clear']}"  tabindex="16" onclick="javascript:clearConfirm();unsetDoIt()"  onchange="setFlag(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for the reply..

I resolved this by writing style with image.. added Value=""..

My problem resolved..

I found another way to reset in javascript.. That is calling script mentioned below

> document.form[0].reset();